# Vertex coloring on a 3-regular simple graph with 10 vertices

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Given such graph, it is known that the chromatic number is 3.
If we remove an arbitrary edge from $G$ to get $G'$, prove that the chromatic number of $G'$ is still 3.
Since $\chi(G)=3$, the upper bound for $\chi(G')$ would be 3.
If the removed edge was on a triangle, then the clique number for $G'$ would be 2 assuming $G$ had only one triangle. In this case, $2\leq\chi(G')\leq3$.
I am stuck on how to prove the lower bound is 3 instead of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be 3-regular with $\chi(G)=3$. Assume we can remove an edge $ab$ from $G$ to achieve $\chi(G')=2$. Then clearly, $a$ and $b$ must have the same colour (red, say) in a red/blue-colouring of $G'$. Now each blue vertex is incident with exactly three edges, and each red vertex except $a,b$ is incident with three edges, and $a,b$ are incident with two edges. On the other hand, each edge is incident with a blue and a red vertex. Hence by counting the edges $e$ of $G'$ in two ways, we find
$$ 3b=e=3\cdot(r-2)+2\cdot 2$$
where the right hand side is not a multiple of $3$ - contradiction!

Comment: Wow. I didn't think about using contradiction. Thank you very much!